# Why is this sequence of ideals an ascending chain? In proof of irreducible ideals are primary.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $P$ be an irreducible ideal in commutative ring $R$.  Suppose $ab \in P$, $a \notin P$, and define $A_n = \{b^n x : x \in R\} \cap P$.  Then "clearly $A_n \subset A_{n+1}$" says D&F.  But CLEARLY it's a descending chain as $bA_n = A_{n+1}$ and $bA_n \subset A_n$.  Why do they say CLEARLY!!!!!! AHHHHH

Thanks.

### Picture of Proof:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an image of the proof?

Comment: Yep.  One second.

Comment: it's $A_n=\{x:b^nx\in P\}$

Comment: @Kaiten, yeah, you're right!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, $A_n=\{b^nx:x∈R\}∩P\supseteq \{b^n(bx):x∈R\}∩P=A_{n+1}$, since $bx\in R$ whenever $x\in R$.

The only unclear thing is, why can't they be equal.  And this is equivalent to saying, we cannot write $1 = bc$ for some $c\in R$.  And this follows since $b\in P, 1\notin P$; since $P$ is an ideal, then $\forall c\in R, P\ni bc \neq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

The text says that
$$
A_n=\{x\in R: a^nx\in Q\}
$$

With your different notation,
$$
A_n=\{x\in R: b^nx\in P\}
$$
because you have $P$ in place of $Q$ and $a\notin P$ instead of $b\notin Q$.

Let $x\in A_n$: then $b^nx\in P$, so $bb^nx=b^{n+1}x\in P$. Hence $x\in A_{n+1}$.

You're interpreting the definition of $A_n$ in a wrong fashion.